# Symfony2 Login use_referer not working

Tags: php, symfony

Here's my security.yml for user login:

```
user_secured_area:
        pattern: /*
        anonymous: ~
        provider: user
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
            use_referer: true
            username_parameter: _email
        logout:
            path: logout
            target: /
```

I've checked the profiler for HTTP_REFERRER and i've got the correct referer. However upon login, it is redirected to the root URL and not the referer URL. Any idea on this or have i missed out something?

The controller:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request){

    $session = $request->getSession();

    //get login error
    if($request->attributes->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)){
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }
    else if(null!==$session && $session->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)){
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }
    else{
        $error = "";
    }

    //repopulate username
    $lastEmail = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME); // a ? true : false

    return $this->render('BazaarBundle:Login:login.html.twig', array('last_email' => $lastEmail, 'error' => $error));
}
```

The twig:

```
<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="_email" value="{{ last_email }}" />

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

<button type="submit">login</button>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default behavior is to redirect on the asked page after login.

The **use_referer** option is used only if no URL is stored in session.
Otherwise, you're redirected to the default target path (which can be defined by using the **default_target_path** option) or the default page ('/') if no parameters defined.

Please look into the **Session Attributes** ine the Symfony debugger (when you're on the login page). Do you have a **_security.yourfirewall.target_path** record ? What is the value ?

**EDIT:** It seems that the session variable is only defined if you're automatically redirected to the login page (for exemple when trying to acces to a secured area without the required rights).

Another possibility is to add an hidden field named _target_path with the wanted value (exemple below).

Adding target_path by the form (maybe it should be good to check if it's not empty):

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ app.request.headers.get('referer') }}" />
```

Cheers

Comment: It says there "No session attributes", how can I make it whenever the user login, he will be redirected back to his previous page if available? Do i need to setup extra sessions for the HTTP_REFERER?

Comment: Can you update your question with the login form template and the loginAction ? 

Simple question, why don't you use a bundle like FOSUserBundle ? This is a fantastic bundle and it does almost everything related to authentication ?

Comment: I've updated my question, i don't use it because I have a more complex user management, i need a few login pages like admin login, superadmin login and user login with different roles.

Comment: Hum ok. Well i don't know why you don't have target_path in session but you can try to add a hidden field in your form with the value of the referer...

i'll edit my answer

Comment: Ok thanks that worked, but normally there would be a session attribute there? I went to the login page using a {{ path('login' )}} anchor from a page.

Comment: Well i'm not 100% sure that the session variable is always there... It is possible that this variable is defined only if you try to access a secured area and you do not have rights. At this point you are automatically redirected to the login (and then maybe then you have a session variable)? EDIT: I checked and, in fact, if i attempt to click directly on a login link without being redirected automatically, i don't have the session attribute

Comment: Yes, the _target_path session attribute is only set when you try to reach a restricted url, not a public url.